# Is there a theory for cellular automata propagating signals in straight lines?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry, cellular-automata

Is there a theory explaining how a cellular automata can propagate signals in straight lines?

For example, this video shows how some "signals" travel down at a diagonal, even though they are composed of 5 white cells.

[image: https://cldup.com/vOROsYM4H0.thumb.png]

What I'm wondering is, has any work been done to describe the different cases or general models for how different numbers of "white cells" can travel in different angles in a grid? So in the video, there are 5 white cells, traveling at roughly a 45 degree angle. But what about 6 white cells, what about 20, or even just 1? And what about a 44 degree angle, or a 44.995 degree (some very precise) angle? What are the general patterns for how the cells move at each step?

Basically, what would the rules be for those types of "signal propagations", or general formulas based on angle and number of cells, how to make it move along a path. That sort of thing. Has any work been done in this area?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  [Bresenham's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) seems somewhat relevant.

Comment: How do you define a straight line on a discrete set of points?

Comment: @A.P. rewrote the question, let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: Most likely that depends on the specific rules of your automaton. For the case of Conway's Game of Life a few oblique spaceships, i.e. "shapes" that travel neither diagonally or orthogonally, are [known](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Category:Oblique_spaceships). Apparently it is also [possible](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Spaceship#Spaceship_Speed) to construct a spaceship that moves in a direction with an arbitrary rational slope, but I couldn't find a reference. You may also be interested in this [database](http://fano.ics.uci.edu/ca/) of gliders in Life-like cellular automata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the computer science point of view, there is a survey by Marianne Delorme and Jacques Mazoyer: [Signals on Cellular Automata](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4471-0129-1_9).

From the dynamical system point of view, people sometimes talk about *defects* or *particles* or *kinks*, which are similar to what you would call a signal.  See for example the relevant section of [this survey](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-30440-3_178) by Marcus Pivato and the references therein.

You could also check out [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0167-2789(96)00259-X) (and related) articles by James Hanson and James Crutchfield on what they call the *computational mechanics* of cellular automata.